# What is $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}/n (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, cyclic-groups

Is $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}/n (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}/(m\mathbb{Z} +n \mathbb{Z})$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The easy explanation is that you are modding out by $m$, then modding out by $n$, therefore to do it one step, you mod out both of them: i.e. the subgroup generated by both $m$ and $n$.

A calculation based on the isomorphism theorems is to observe $$n(\mathbb{Z} / m\mathbb{Z}) = (n \mathbb{Z} + m \mathbb{Z})/m \mathbb{Z}$$ and so

$$(\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}) / n(\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z})
= (\mathbb{Z} / m \mathbb{Z}) / ((n \mathbb{Z} + m \mathbb{Z})/m \mathbb{Z})
= \mathbb{Z} / (n \mathbb{Z} + m \mathbb{Z}) $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ be generated by $a$.  Then $n(\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $na$.  So the result is $\mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$ where $d=\text{gcd}(n,m)$, which is indeed the same as $\mathbb{Z}/(m\mathbb{Z}+n\mathbb{Z})$.

Comment: but $mZ + nZ = dZ$ no? Z/dZ should not be the same as Z/(m/d)Z then...